# Add shadow to window

Tags: css, xul

I have next XUL file:

```
<window id="SomeWindow" html:role="alert" onload="init(event);" sizemode="normal"  hidechrome="true" orient="horizontal">
  <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://browser/content/test.js"/>
  <button id="SomeButton"/>
</window>
```

and CSS file:

```
#SomeWindow{
  width: 1px;
  margin: 4px -1px 4px 0;
  background-color: #FFCA80;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px black;
}
```

Adding `box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px black;` doesn't helps...

Any ideas how I can add shadow effect.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. A shadow of what?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying. What is this supposed to look like? Do you have an image?

Comment: It should looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/2evSK.jpg

Comment: What HTML element will the window appear in? You would have to add the drop shadow to that.

Comment: not sure what you mean under 'What HTML element'. I need to add for 'window' element in xul

Comment: Then add the drop shadow to the window not the button...right?

Comment: I did it, but no results...
 #SomeWindow {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px black;
}

Comment: You can't have a shadow on something with 'display:none'...it's not logical. Also that's not what you posted CSS says. You used #SomeButton

Comment: Is `width:1px` correct...that seems very samll?

Comment: It's just test data, I have changed it to 100, but result the same

Comment: Then unfortunately, I cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the close tag for your script. I recreated your code and it works now:

```
<window id="SomeWindow" html:role="alert" onload="init(event);" sizemode="normal"  hidechrome="true" orient="horizontal">
      <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://browser/content/test.js"/></script>
      <button id="SomeButton"/>
    </window>

<style>
    #SomeWindow {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 4px -1px 4px 0;
  background-color: #FFCA80;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px black;
}
</style>
```